# What is the proper method to receive consumed costs by virtual machine

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory

I have faced some difficulties with receiving spent money by Azure Virtual Machine.

For example there is metrics for receiving consumption of CPU Usage and CPU Credits Consumed.
`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmname}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=Percentage%20CPU,CPU%20Credits%20Consumed&timespan=2019-05-20T00:00:00Z/2019-05-21T00:00:00Z`

So I receive something like this:

```
 {"cost"=>0.04, "timestamp"=>"2019-05-20T00:26:00Z"}},
 {"cost"=>0.03, "timestamp"=>"2019-05-20T00:27:00Z"}},
 {"cost"=>0.03, "timestamp"=>"2019-05-20T00:28:00Z"}}
```

For whole day it gives me about *57* units (it is important) if I sum all of 1440 results.

However there is also such thing as Usage Details. When I use it:
`https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-01-01`

This request responses with such response:

```
"properties"=>
     {"billingPeriodId"=>"/subscriptions/subscription_id/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/201906",
      "usageStart"=>"2019-05-20T00:00:00.0000000Z",
      "usageEnd"=>"2019-05-20T23:59:59.0000000Z",
    "instanceId"=>"/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/CLOUD-SHELL-STORAGE-EASTUS/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/name",
      "instanceName"=>"name",
      "instanceLocation"=>"AP East",
      "meterId"=>"some_id",
      "usageQuantity"=>24,
      "pretaxCost"=>24.75,
      "currency"=>"RUB",
      "subscriptionGuid"=>"some guid",
      "subscriptionName"=>"MSDN",
```

So it shows 24.75 RUB for 20th of May.

I would like to know what is the correct way to get proper costs consuming by virtual machine. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the type of VM? reserved one?

Comment: I am not sure. Where can I check it?

Comment: it shows up at the time of creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What resources are charged when deploying a VM?
```

to understand how much does the VM cost , we need to understand what are the resources being used when we use any VM. VMs acquire costs for the VM itself, any premium software running on the VM, the storage account\managed disk associated with the VM, and the networking bandwidth transfers from the VM.

We can get price and metadata information for resource used in an azure subscription using resource rate card API.

Here is the sample rate card api URL.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-Id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version={api-version}&$filter=OfferDurableId eq ’{OfferDurableId}’ and Currency eq ’{Currency}’ and Locale eq ’{Locale}’ and RegionInfo eq ’{RegionInfo}’’
```

- Set {OfferDurableId} to a valid Offer ID code (e.g., MS-AZR-0026P). See Microsoft Azure Offer Details for more information on the list of available Offer IDs, country/region availability, and billing currency. The Offer ID parameter consists of the “MS-AZR-“ prefix, plus the Offer ID number.
- Set {Currency} to the currency in which the resource rates need to be provided.
- Set {Locale} to the culture in which the resource metadata needs to be localized.
- Set {RegionInfo} to the 2 letter ISO code where the offer was purchased.

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-Id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq ’MS-AZR-0003p’ and Currency eq ’USD’ and Locale eq ’en-US’ and RegionInfo eq ’US’

sample response:

```
{  
   "OfferTerms": [],  
   "Meters": [  
      {  
         "MeterId": "1822fcc4-6059-4cbb-a132-54a187aaac46",  
         "MeterName": "Compute Hours",  
         "MeterCategory": "Virtual Machines",  
         "MeterSubCategory": "Basic_D6 VM (Non-Windows)",  
         "Unit": "Hours",  
         "MeterTags": [],  
         "MeterRates": {  
            "0": 3.136  
         },  
         "EffectiveDate": "2015-02-01T00:00:00Z",  
         "IncludedQuantity": 0.0  
      },  
      {  
         "MeterId": "3c5324ad-eb8c-44c6-af9a-6741ae75fc90",  
         "MeterName": "Data Transfer Out at 500 Mbps (GB)",  
         "MeterCategory": "Networking",  
         "MeterSubCategory": "ExpressRoute (IXP)",  
         "Unit": "GB",  
         "MeterTags": [],  
         "MeterRates": {  
            "0": 0.1  
         },  
         "EffectiveDate": "2014-08-01T00:00:00Z",  
         "IncludedQuantity": 2048.0  
      },  

      {  
         "MeterId": "9ee077eb-c902-46ef-b7f9-2caeade852e0",  
         "MeterName": "Compute Hours",  
         "MeterCategory": "Cloud Services",  
         "MeterSubCategory": "A6 Cloud Services",  
         "Unit": "Hours",  
         "MeterTags": [],  
         "MeterRates": {  
           "0": 0.71  
         },  
         "EffectiveDate": "2013-12-01T00:00:00Z",  
         "IncludedQuantity": 0.0  
      },  
   …     
   ]  
   "Currency": "USD",  
   "Locale": "en-US",  
   "IsTaxIncluded": false,  
   "MeterRegion": "US West",  
   "Tags": []   
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I has some issues with query parameters but I guess it is good now.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.